# Permission Denied when writing file on internal storage from Xamarin

Tags: android, file, xamarin, permissions

I'm trying to do the following:

```
        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
        string maindir = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Pictures");
        string filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName);
        var newFile = Path.Combine(maindir, filename);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newFile);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
            }
        }
```

By using `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory`, I should be getting a folder within the *internal storage* (incidentally, I also provided external storage writing permissions, but that should not be relevant - and it didn't resolve the issue). The rest of the code is near verbatim from Xamarin.Essentials documentation.

On the line with File.OpenWrite, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, saying "Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.companyname.peerpeek/files/Pictures/20231115_154707.jpg' is denied".

From everything I've read, this should not be happening. So: is this a bug or am I missing something obvious here?

For good measure: I get this error both when running it on an emulated Pixel 5 (Android 13) and when I debug on my own Phone (Android 12).

[Edit] As requested: here's the full Exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.companyname.peerpeek/files/Pictures/20231115_163542.jpg' is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x000e7] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:196 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:91 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenWrite (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:271 
  at PeerPeek.MainPage.LoadPhotoAsync (Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult photo) [0x00187] in C:\Users
icksa\source\repos\PeerPeek\PeerPeek\PeerPeek\MainPage.xaml.cs:88
```

Comment: Add full exception

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(newFile);` That should be: `Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDir);`

Comment: @blackapps OMG I could have missed this a million times over. I suspect that indeed it created a subfolder with the same name as the one I was going to use as the filename and this blocked the creation of the file!
What is the proper way to close this question as the solution turns out to have nothing to do with what's in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Directory.CreateDirectory(newFile);

That should be:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDir);
```

Now the file cannot be created because there is already a directory with the same name.

Indeed action denied.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the photo without using `Directory.CreateDirectory(newFile);`. It will be stored in the local storage.

```
  var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
  string maindir = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Pictures");
  string filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName);
  var newFile = Path.Combine(maindir, filename);
  using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
  using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
  await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
```

Comment: What happens if the subfolder "Pictures" doesn't exist? Will OpenWrite create it on the fly or will it fail (I'm guessing the last)?
Maybe you could adjust your answer to what @blackapps suggested in the comments to the question?